# How can i put delay in displaying the final result of my maze

Tags: java, eclipse, maze

i am creating a maze generation application. what i want to happen is that, when i run my program, it will show the animation on how the maze was created (it will show how it knocks the wall to create a path).

i tried to put delay on some of its parts but it won't run.thank you for the HUGE HELP!
here's the code:

```
public class Maze extends JPanel {

private Room[][] rooms;// m x n matrix of rooms
private ArrayList<Wall> walls; // List of walls
private Random rand;// for random wall
private int height;// height of matrix
private int width;// width of matrix
private int num;// incrementor
private JoinRoom ds;// union paths

// paint methods //
private int x_cord; // x-axis rep
private int y_cord;// y-axis rep
private int roomSize;
private int randomWall;
private int create;
int mazectr;

public static int m;// these are variables for the size of maze (m x n)
public static int n;

public Maze(int m, int n) {

    JPanel j = new JPanel();
    final JFrame f = new JFrame();
    this.height = m;
    this.width = n;
    rooms = new Room[m][n];
    walls = new ArrayList<Wall>((m - 1) * (n - 1));
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    generateRandomMaze();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final JLabel jl = new JLabel("Time Taken: " + (endTime-startTime) + "ms");
    final JButton y = new JButton("OK");
    j.add(jl);
    j.add(y);
    f.add(j);
    y.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            f.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(100, 100);


    //jl.setLocation(1000, 1500);
    //jl.setBounds(0, 0, 110, 130);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 700));


   }


private void generateRandomMaze() {
    generateInitialRooms();// see next method
    ds = new JoinRoom(width * height);
    rand = new Random(); // here is the random room generator
    num = width * height;
    while (num > 1) {
       // when we pick a random wall we want to avoid the borders getting eliminated
        randomWall = rand.nextInt(walls.size());
        Wall temp = walls.get(randomWall);
        // we will pick two rooms randomly 
        int roomA = temp.currentRoom.y + temp.currentRoom.x * width;
        int roomB = temp.nextRoom.y + temp.nextRoom.x * width;

        // check roomA and roomB to see if they are already members 
        if (ds.find(roomA) != ds.find(roomB)) {
            walls.remove(randomWall);
            ds.unionRooms(ds.find(roomA), ds.find(roomB));
            temp.isGone = true;
            temp.currentRoom.adj.add(temp.nextRoom);
            temp.nextRoom.adj.add(temp.currentRoom);
            num--;
        }// end of if

    }// end of while

}

 // name the room to display
private int roomNumber = 0;
private static Label input;
private static Label input2;

/**
 * Sets the grid of rooms to be initially boxes
 * This is self explanitory, we are only creating an reverse L for all
 * The rooms and there is an L for the border
 */
private void generateInitialRooms() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            // create north walls
            rooms[i][j] = new Room(i, j);
            if (i == 0) {
                rooms[i][j].north = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            } else {
                rooms[i][j].north = new Wall(rooms[i - 1][j], rooms[i][j]);
                walls.add(rooms[i][j].north);
            }
            if (i == height - 1) {
                rooms[i][j].south = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            }
            if (j == 0) {
                rooms[i][j].west = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            } else {
                rooms[i][j].west = new Wall(rooms[i][j - 1], rooms[i][j]);
                walls.add(rooms[i][j].west);
            }
            if (j == width - 1) {
                rooms[i][j].east = new Wall(rooms[i][j]);
            }
            rooms[i][j].roomName = roomNumber++;// we will name the rooms
        }
    }
    // initalize entrance and exit
    rooms[0][0].west.isGone = true;// you can replace .west.isGone with .north.isGone
    // this is just saying the roomName for top left is 0 
    rooms[0][0].roomName = 0;
    // we will remove the south wall of the last room
    rooms[height - 1][width - 1].south.isGone = true;
    // this is just saying the roomName for bottom right is the last element in the mxn room matrix
    rooms[height - 1][width - 1].roomName = (height * width);
}

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    x_cord = 40;
    y_cord = 40;
   Thread t = new Thread();
    // could have taken height as well as width
    // just need something to base the roomsize
    roomSize = (width - x_cord) / width + 20;

    // temp variables used for painting
    int x = x_cord;
    int y = y_cord;

    for (int i = 0; i <= height - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= width - 1; j++) {
            if (!(rooms[i][j].north.isGone)) {
                g.drawLine(x, y, x + roomSize, y);
            }//end of north if
            // west wall not there draw the line
            if (rooms[i][j].west.isGone == false) {
                g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + roomSize);
            }// end of west if
            if ((i == height - 1) && rooms[i][j].south.isGone == false) {
                g.drawLine(x, y + roomSize, x + roomSize,
                        y + roomSize);
            }// end of south if
            if ((j == width - 1) && rooms[i][j].east.isGone == false) {
                g.drawLine(x + roomSize, y, x + roomSize,
                        y + roomSize);
            }// end of east if
            x += roomSize;// change the horizontal
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception e) {};

            t.start();
        }// end of inner for loop
        x = x_cord;
        y += roomSize;

    }// end of outer for loop

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // use JFrame to put the created panel on 
   String path = "E:\\Iskul\\trys\\tryy\\bin\\GUI.jpg";
   File file = new File("E:\\Iskul\\trys\\tryy\\bin\\GUI.jpg");
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
   File fileRec = new File("E:\\Iskul\\trys\\tryy\\bin\\re.jpg");
   BufferedImage imageRec = ImageIO.read(fileRec);
   File fileHex = new File("E:\\Iskul\\trys\\tryy\\bin\\hexx.jpg");
   BufferedImage imageHex = ImageIO.read(fileHex);


    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prim's Algorithm");
    final JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    final JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
    final JTextField input2 = new JTextField(10); 
    final JButton jb = new JButton(new ImageIcon(imageRec));
    jb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    final JButton jb1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon(imageHex));
    jb1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    final JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));


    jb.setLocation(100, 10);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(795, 501));
    jp.add(input);
    jp.add(input2);
    frame.add(jp);
    jp.add(jb);
    jp.add(jb1);
    //jb.setImage(image);


    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //int mazectr = 1;
            int m = Integer.valueOf(input.getText());   
            int n = Integer.valueOf(input2.getText());
            frame.remove(label);
            frame.remove(jp);
            //frame.add(new Maze(m,n));
            frame.getContentPane().add(new Maze(m, n));
            frame.pack();


    }});

jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
            //int m = Integer.valueOf(input.getText()); 
            //int n = Integer.valueOf(input2.getText());
            Hexa1 hexa = new Hexa1();
            hexa.main();
            //hexa.run();
        }
    });


   }}// end of main
```

Comment: I am confused, as to, where do you want to put the delay ?

Comment: puhh thats a wall of code. pls show us what you have tried and what won't run.

Comment: I didn't go through your code but what I saw was that the delay is 50 millisec which means 0.05 seconds. Maybe you should try a bigger number. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code wont work, you cant do an sleep in the Paint method, because if you do so, he wont draw, he just waits and at the end he'll draw your whole image.

If you want to do a nice effect, you should draw one step after the other but you should be aware that this is a lot of work to realize...